# Squid proxy, reacheable but sites still bocked by dns

Tags: networking, dns, proxy

I wanted to host a proxy on one of my PC, and so I installed and configured *Squid* on it.

I want to use this proxy to bypass web URL filtering from another position.

I can reach my PC, but there is a problem:

After configuring Firefox to use my proxy (Options → Advanced → net → settings → Proxy HTTP) I've noticed that websites are still blocked, but if I go on something like `whatismyip.com` I see the IP of my PC that is hosting the proxy. 
Why is that happening ? And is there a way to fix this?

I also used *Glype*, and I didn't have issue with it, but I wanted to switch to a different kind of proxy to avoid problem with some websites/javascript.

Comment: Are you using a corporate DNS server? 
You could try to change it to a public DNS server like 8.8.8.8 (googles).

Comment: @MikaelKjær Yes but the other DNS are blocked. I don't know how this proxy actually works, but shouldn't my request be sent to the proxy, and after it takes care to use the DNS that i setted in his confing?

Comment: Depends how you set your system up. DNS requests are usually not proxied and even if they are, you're still using the restricted DNS server. Have a look at [this](https://www.proxifier.com/documentation/v3/dns.htm) if you're using windows. If googles is blocked, try out opendns: 208.67.222.222

Comment: @MikaelKjær thanks for the help, so i should install proxifier and add a not blocked DNS that I can reach? At the same time i think that all dns are blocked, probably they block also the port used by them...